# Python, decorators, functools wraps

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper, functools

I am building architecture for my code and decided to try a simple problem. Here I have code including decorators.

```
from functools import wraps


class Parent():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def oper(self, b):
        return self.a + b


class Inherit(Parent):
    def adder(self, func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapping(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*[i**2 for i in args], **kwargs)
        return wrapping

    @adder
    def oper(self, b):
        return super().oper(b)


a = Parent(10)
print(a.oper(10))
b = Inherit(10)
print(b.oper(10))
```

When I start it I receive exception like:

> TypeError: adder() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'

I have no idea how to make it work because I thought the attribute `func` in the decorator must be automatically assigned when you initialise decorator with `@` in the line before object.

Comment: Remove the `self` from `adder`. It's not being called as an instance method, so doesn't receive a `self`. Defining decorators in classes is very questionable to begin with.

Comment: declare your decorator out of your class, and take out self

Comment: And when you remove `self`, use `@staticmethod` decorator.